# Polymer core-list - only show enough items to fill the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, polymer

I'm experimenting with [core-list](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-list.html).

From the docs:

> For performance reasons, not every item in the list is rendered at once; instead a small subset of actual template elements (enough to fill the viewport) are rendered and reused as the user scrolls.

and regarding the attribute 'height':

> The approximate height of a list item, in pixels. This is used only for determining the number of physical elements to render based on the viewport size of the list. Items themselves may vary in height between each other depending on their data model. There is typically no need to adjust this value unless the average size is much larger or smaller than the default.

So, if I have

```
<core-list style="height: 1000px" height="500"></core-list>
```

and my list items are 500px high, my list should display two items.

If my list items are 800px high, my list should display one item.

Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, it will load some items but not a definite answer how many. For example if your core list has height 500 and you elements have height 50 it might load just 6 elements, even that you have for example 100 elements.

I tried it and i had a problem that i wanted to be shown 15 elements, but it was showing only 11 even that there was space enough to show 15 elements. 
In my case i just adjusted the height of list, to show enough elements so that the scroll was also shown. And when the user scrolled other elements are loaded.